# Ticket Tracking Software w/ Good Email Integration and Decent Navigation?

Tags: bug-tracking, email, ticket-system

I am looking for a simple system to manage inbound emails from a support mailbox for a group with about 3 support people.  I've looked at [OTRS](http://otrs.org/) which seems to have the features that we need.  Unfortunately, so far the UI still looks like a confusing mess.

Are there any good FOSS tools that would meet this need?  I've heard murmurings that something called fooogzeeebugzo might have similar features, but it seems quite expensive for such simple needs.

Answer (score 9):

Did you try [IssueBurner](http://issueburner.com/)? It was designed for this purpose. You can forward your mailbox (e.g. support@yourcompany.com) to a IssueBurner group and you can track the inbound mails until they are closed.

Here is a link to their video: http://issueburner.com/a/video

Answer (score 6):

I have to agree, Fogbugz is probably the best out there. I have used both the hosted version and the purchased version which I hosted.  It is top-notch.

Answer (score 4):

My company recently started using Mojo Helpdesk: [www.mojohelpdesk.com](http://www.mojohelpdesk.com). It's a hosted service, not FOSS, but it's pretty cheap and the interface is slick.

Answer (score 4):

[BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) is free, open source, and widely used.   It has integration with incoming email.   In other words, it will accept an incoming email and turn it into a support ticket.

Comment: Corey, a little disclaimer on this and similar posts that you're (one of ?) the developers of bugtracker.net would lend more credibility.

Comment: What about the fogbugz ad in here ?

Comment: @mm2001 - If I had written, "BugTracker.NET is the BEST!!", then, yeah, it would be deceptive for me not to say I'm the author.  But here, I just made a dry, objective statement.   About software that I share with the world *FOR FREE*.  That offends you?

Answer (score 3):

TicketDesk- C# issue tracking system and support system

http://www.codeplex.com/TicketDesk

TicketDesk is efficient and designed to do only one thing, facilitate communications between help desk staff and end users. The overriding design goal is to be as simple and frictionless for both users and help desk staff as is possible.

TicketDesk is an asp.net web application written in C# targeting the .net 3.5 framework. It includes a simple database with support for SQL 2005 Express or SQL Server 2005. It can leverage SQL server for membership and role based security or integrate with windows authentication and Active Directory groups.

Answer (score 2):

[RT - Request Tracker](http://bestpractical.com/rt/) handles inbound mail.  I'm working to add inbound mail support to [TicketDesk](http://codeplex.com/ticketdesk), but that might be a little while before that makes it into a release.

Answer (score 2):

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) is great as others have mentioned.  I use it for my bug/feature tracking system, but I like to separate out my support ticketing system for my support staff to use.  Another tool that has great email integration also is called [HelpSpot](http://www.userscape.com/products/helpspot/), they have hosted and non-hosted versions for purchase, depending on your budget.  It has a lot of great features, that make the prices worth it.  Take the tour and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Scope out [SmarterTrack](http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterTrack/Features/Customer-Service-Software-Web-Interface.aspx), [Help Desk Software](http://www.smartertools.com/smartertrack/help-desk-software.aspx) from SmarterTools:

Answer (score 0):

We use FogBugz...er, "fooogzeeebugzo"...and while it may be a bit expensive for your needs, it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

bugzilla is more of an issue tracker than a request tracker, but it can be configured to handle email-based status tracking. That said, I think Steven has it- RT is the standard recommendation for this that I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

The on-demand version of Fogbugz is a pretty cheap option for just a few people, and works really well. We did that for a while before moving it inhouse.

Answer (score 0):

I've used fogbugz for over 12 months now and more and more I'm finding one of the most valuable features is the in built email support. I've got an on demand account and I'm finding more and more that I don't even check my email in the morning as all my business correspondence is put straight into fogbugz.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that FOSS is your primary desire and I definitely agree with this.  If I were to limit myself to FOSS, I would go with RT 3.8, http://blog.bestpractical.com/2008/07/today-were-rele.html#screenshots

However, if you are willing to entertain commercial solutions and are looking for a Helpdesk-"ish" application.  I just deployed [WebHelpDesk](http://www.webhelpdesk.com) with great success at my current employment, where I am the primary sysadmin and Corporate IT person.  They just released a new version, 9.1.1 and it is very well done.  The email integration is superb and beyond what I have seen with most other FOSS and commercial issue/bug trackers, given that it is built to run a Helpdesk and not be a software or source code issue tracker.  It runs on Windows and *nix, they have a great [demo](http://demo.helpdesk.com) and you can obtain a 30 day trial [installer](http://downloads.webhelpdesk.com).  I have become a big fan of this software and think it has a reasonable price of $250/year/technician (support person).

If you want more info on how we deployed it, please email me and I'd be happy to discuss it at length.  I have no more connection with them than I am a very happy customer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the tips.  For the moment, I am looking heavily at [eTicket](http://www.eticketsupport.com/) as it was trivial to setup and seems to be developing nicely at the moment.  I may look at RT as well, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second the suggestion for RT.  See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225350/what-ticketing-system-would-you-suggest#387302) for more thoughts and details on our setup.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience I can recommend using [Bridgetrak](http://www.helpdesksoftware.com).
It works pretty smooth in  our environment and includes rich helpdesk functionality for powerful tickets tracking.

I have a lot of experience using this tools  - feel free to ask any questions!

Answer (score 0):

As most of the answers are a little bit outdated, I would definitely recommend OsTicket (http://osticket.com/), a great open source project that offers lots of customization and a user friendly interface.

I have been using it for the last two years and I would rather choose OsTicket than OTRS or RT.